# Unicorn on Heroku throwing weird errors which causes H13 server errors. What's killing my unicorns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, unicorn

I have a Rails 4 app running on Heroku that has suddenly started to throw a lot of H13 errors. I've traced it through the logs and see a lot of errors with unicorn complaining about `memoized object is not a string`. The processes are then reaped by a SIGIOT. Here's the exact error:

```
unicorn_http.rl:295: write_value: Assertion `rb_type((VALUE)(f)) == RUBY_T_STRING && "memoized object is not a string"' failed.
```

The errors can also look like this:

```
unicorn_http.rl:296: write_value: Assertion `(!!((!(((VALUE)(f) & RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK) || !!(((VALUE)(f) & ~((VALUE)RUBY_Qnil)) == 0)) && (int)(((struct RBasic*)(f))->flags & RUBY_T_MASK) != RUBY_T_NODE)?(((struct RBasic*)(f))->flags&((((VALUE)1)<<11))):((((int)(long)(f))&RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG)||((((int)(long)(f))&RUBY_FLONUM_MASK) == RUBY_FLONUM_FLAG)))) && "unfrozen object"' failed.
```

It happens on many different routes and I can't seem to figure out what it going on. I run a very stock unicorn config:

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 2)
timeout 29
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

And here is snippet of Heroku logs with the error:

```
Sep 15 15:38:42 #{app} heroku/router:  at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="#{path}" host=host.org request_id=6af16b9e-02ff-494e-8c8c-11f060f3b8fe fwd="109.63.24.000" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=503 bytes=1187 
Sep 15 15:38:42 #{app} app/web.1:  unicorn worker[1] -p 4635 -c ./config/unicorn.rb: unicorn_http.rl:295: write_value: Assertion `rb_type((VALUE)(f)) == RUBY_T_STRING && "memoized object is not a string"' failed. 
Sep 15 15:38:42 #{app} app/web.1:  I, [2014-09-15T22:38:41.878914 #675]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready 
Sep 15 15:38:42 #{app} app/web.1:  E, [2014-09-15T22:38:41.835934 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 672 SIGIOT (signal 6)> worker=1 

...

Sep 15 15:26:52 #{app} app/web.1:  unicorn worker[0] -p 4635 -c ./config/unicorn.rb: unicorn_http.rl:295: write_value: Assertion `rb_type((VALUE)(f)) == RUBY_T_STRING && "memoized object is not a string"' failed. 
Sep 15 15:26:52 #{app} app/web.1:  E, [2014-09-15T22:26:52.483577 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 487 SIGIOT (signal 6)> worker=0 
Sep 15 15:26:52 #{app} heroku/router:  at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="#{path}" host=host.org request_id=92fbf67f-56b1-4144-917a-c3d29171f631 fwd="76.234.45.000" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=18ms status=503 bytes=1208
```

Request queueing is normally <10ms on this app and this seems to just have started recently but I haven't changed the unicorn setup in ages. The app is a Heroku app running Rails 4.1.1 with Ruby 2.0.0 on Unicorn 4.8.2. It uses memecache with dalli to do some minimal caching. The requests fail with the H13 error immediately so I'm not hitting the 29 second timeout set in the unicorn.rb config.

Comment: It seems somebody else had that error in the past: https://gist.github.com/stefanoverna/7661660 - any reason why you're not using the latest stable Ruby? There have been a lot of fixes between 2.0 and 2.1

Comment: No reason other than the lack of time and other priorities. An upgrade to 2.1.2 has been on my list for a while so I'll give that a shot, along with upgrading unicorn to the latest stable version 4.8.3.

Comment: @LukasEklund We're having the same issue. Basically a gradual rise of H13's over several months without any significant changes to our setup. FWIW, we're also running Ruby 2.0.0 on Heroku, and after seeing this post I updated to 2.1.2, hoping for maybe some reduction in H13 connection closed errors. Not only did they persist, but a whole new problem arose due to [2.1.2 leaking memory](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/memory-leaks-with-ruby-2-1-2/644) and causing "memory quota exceeded" errors left and right. Had to rollback to 2.0.0 at the end of a very stressful Monday. And back to square one.